# WP Featured image not showing on Facebook shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I paste the URL of a single post page from my site to my FB fan page it shows a default image and not the featured image I selected as the preview image.

When I paste that same URL in FB's debugger page it shows the image that I selected as the featured image as the og:image

How come the image I selected as the featured image doesn't show up as the preview image? How do I fix it so that it does?

Here is a sigle post page from my site:

http://www.cops.com/your-cousins-on-cops/

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the open graph tags like this:

```
    .....
    meta property="og:title" content=""
    meta property="og:type" content=""
    meta property="og:url" content=""
    meta property="og:image" content=""
    meta property="og:site_name" content=""
    ....
```

instead of these:

```
    ...
    meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#site_name" content="COPS"
    meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#type" content="article"
    meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#locale" content="en_US"
    ...
```

i think maybe solves the problem?

this is the photo, which the fb scraper showed me: http://www.cops.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/The-Reverend-Peytons-Big-Damn-Band.jpg